# Bootstrap Modal override close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have my Bootstrap modal alert. I can handle the click event on the "ok" button like:

```
$('button[data-dismiss="ok"]', confirmModal).on('click', function (event) {
    // ...
});
```

but I want to handle differently the "cancel/modal" button:

```
$('button[data-dismiss="modal"]', confirmModal).on('click', function (event) {
   // ...
});
```

What happens is that when handling the `modal` event, the modal window will be closed, but it will not return the focus to the document for some reason.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGBxOW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
confirmModal.remove();
```

You're hiding the modal just before removing it. So the modal is being removed while hiding it. This explains why you don't see the 'move up' event on closing. The modal simply disappears.

Removing the modal **after** the `hidden.bs.modal` event will solve your issue:

```
confirmModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    confirmModal.remove();
});
```

Hopefully this solves your issue :-)

Comment: thank you. If i put in the "modal" event it works, but not in the "ok" - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKjLJp?editors=1010

Comment: Thats strange. It works for me. Is the modal actually fading out? Or disappearing (like I explained)?

Comment: the modal is fading out in both cases, but for the `ok` it does not fade-in the document as it happens in the `modal` event.

Comment: That only happens when you open the modal for the second time and on click save? The first time works fine for me.

Comment: exactly it works only after the first click, while I would like to make it working every time.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I think it has something to do with your return statement (line 39 of your codepen). JavaScript is being read once chronological. Perhaps you could try to work around this.